# postgreSQL: how to duplicate a row w/ OID as bytea column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to duplicate a row in the "my_file" table as following:

```
insert into my_file (

    file_name,
    file_content 

) select 

    file_name,
    file_content 

from my_file 
where file_name = 'zzz'
```

The file_content column is an oid and therefore contains a reference to the actual file content. The above duplicate is simply copying the reference. How to generate a new value of the file_content in that case ?

Thx.

Comment: Something, like [`file_content = lo_from_bytea(0, lo_get(file_content))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html)?

Comment: But I have to admit, that the `bytea` type is closer to SQL's BLOB concept. If you are worried about duplication, you could just use a separate table for actual `bytea` values, and use its primary key (f.ex. a generated ID) as foreign keys in referenced tables. IMHO that is still better than the old large object concept of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm using JDBC and got initially an issue w/ bytea. Thanks to your feedback I've read the doc. again and solved my issue w/ bytea.  You can answer and I'll will accept if you like.